# Retrieve only date from datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, etl, derived-column

I  am using a derived column with ssis with this condition :

```
UpdatedDate == (DT_DATE)"9999-12-31" ? (DT_DATE)CreatedDate : (DT_DATE)UpdatedDate
```

This is my actual output, I'm storing the result in BI_StartDate :

```
EmployeeId createdDate updatedDate BI_StartDate
54         2013-07-10  9999-12-31  2013-07-10 00:00:00.0000000
245        2016-06-29  2016-07-03  2016-07-03 00:00:00.0000000
```

I want to get only the date:

```
EmployeeId createdDate updatedDate BI_StartDate
54         2013-07-10  9999-12-31  2013-07-10
245        2016-06-29  2016-07-03  2016-07-03
```

Comment: Is `2016-07-03 00:00:00.0000000` value in the database? if so, the reason is the datatype choice in the database, it's a `datetime2(7)`. Change it to `date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively (for [Knowledge Sake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15)),

Use `DT_DBDATE` instrad of `DT_DATE`

```
UpdatedDate == (DT_DBDATE)"9999-12-31" ? (DT_DBDATE)CreatedDate : (DT_DBDATE)UpdatedDate
```

Answer (score 3):

You only need to cast / convert it to date data type by using:

```
CAST(BI_StartDate AS DATE)
```

or :

```
CONVERT(DATE, BI_StartDate)
```

Comment: OK, you were faster ;-)